# Do we know when the initial topology coincides with product topology?

Tags: general-topology, universal-property

This question comes from a beginner undergraduate who just read the definitions and likes to wonder things, so it is possible I'm asking too much. I appreciate your patience.

**The setup**

Let $(X_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a family of topological spaces and $(f_{i}\colon X\to X_{i})_{i\in I}$ a family of maps defined on $X$.

We put the initial (or weak) topology on $X$. We hold this for a while.

Now we take the cartesian product $\prod X_{i}$ and consider the product topology on it.

From the universal property of the product topology, there is a unique continuous map
\begin{equation}
X\to \prod X_{i}
\end{equation}
making the 'usual' diagrams commute.

Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Evaluation) that this map is known as the 'evaluation map'. They also say that this map is injective if and only if the family $(f_{i})_{i\in I}$ separates points.

**The question**

Do we know conditions under which this will be surjective? What about a homeomorphism?

If this is too general, do we know additional conditions which give such a criterion?

Comment: In your first setup, $X$ can be any set whatsoever, so why do you expect that there should be any meaningful conditions under which the evaluation map should be surjective? Also the maps $f_i$ can be anything (for example they may be constant), so the initial topology on $X$ may have nothing to do with the topologies on the $X_i$ (and therefore with the product topology on the Cartesian product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is any useful condition for the map $f:X\to\prod X_i$ to be surjective that isn't just a paraphrase of the definition. In practice, it very rarely is surjective.

However, if $f$ is a bijection, then it automatically is a homeomorphism: this follows almost immediately from the definition of the product topology and the initial topology.  Indeed, the initial topology is defined to be generated by sets of the form $f_j^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(\pi_j^{-1}(U))$ where $\pi_j:\prod X_i\to X_j$ is the $j$th projection and $U\subseteq X_j$ is open.  The product topology on $\prod X_i$ is defined to be generated by sets of the form $\pi_j^{-1}(U)$.  So when $f$ is a bijection, the sets generating the topology on $X$ are "the same" as the sets generating the topology on $\prod X_i$ (just pulled back by the bijection $f$), so $f$ is a homeomorphism.  More generally, a similar argument shows that $f$ is automatically a homeomorphism onto its image if it is injective.